# 500 Internal Server Error - register_globals

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, whm

I transferred website to new server(PHP Version 5.3.8) which had "Server API=CGI/FastCGI", website was working fine except one page(public_html/user/index.php). I got error:

**500 Internal Server Error**

Then, I changed Server API to " Apache 2.0 Handler ", now I get blank white page.
phpinfo( ) is showing me register_globals   Off

The .htaccess in public_html/user/ has below content

```
#deny from all

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

#AddHandler x-httpd-php .html

#AddHandler x-httpd-php .htm

#AddType image/x-icon .ico 

php_value display_errors On

#php_value register_globals On

php_value error_reporting E_ALL

#E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

Old server was running PHP Version 5.2.8

Any advise?

Comment: That's not necessarily the problem source. For status 500 errors, look into the `error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

register_globals being deprecated does not explain it giving internal server error, especially if it has been commented out.

You are getting internal server error because you are trying to set values that are not understood or allowed by the server. As with server errors in general, apache's error logs should provide you details of the error.

Based on experience, my first guess would be that the (www) user running your PHP scripts hasn't been given the rights to set php_value:s through .htaccess. To set .htaccess values, you'll need to have in the apache configuration AllowOverride Options or AllowOverride All privilege ("All" includes "Options"). My first thing would be to check that. php_value directives need AllowOverride Options privilege.

Answer (score 0):

`register_globals` has been deprecated since PHP 5.3 and is turned off by default for security reasons.

See the [pHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for response. Is there way to get it working with PHP 5.3. I have seen some import options but do not know if any can work and how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

php_value and php_flag commands are obsolete, and will cause 500 errors on most servers when used in .htaccess. Their settings should be done in a php.ini file or the equivalent on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I myself was having this error.

phpinfo() - in my website was showing as register_globals = off

Found solution through 2 hour r&d web searches - 
edited the php.ini to
register_globals=off

and uploaded it again and website was running within seconds.

Hope this solutions helps somebody to run his/her website.